# ¿Como añadir espaciado de letras en un Qlabel?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Tengo un Qlabel en al cual esta escrita una frase determinada, pero necesito que entre cada letra haya un espaciado determinado por ejmplo de 5px entre cada letra o un espacio entre cada una.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLabel,QWidget
from PyQt5 import Qt

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Hola como estan")
        # Resultado esperado:
        ## H o l a  c o m o  e s t a n
        self.label.setFont(
           Qt.QFont.setLetterSpacing(
               Qt.QFont.PercentageSpacing,
               200
           )
        )

app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

He intentado hacer uso de la propiedad setLetterSpacing pero me lanza el siguiente error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\text.py", line 25, in <module>
    m = Main()
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\text.py", line 16, in __init__
    Qt.QFont.setLetterSpacing(
TypeError: setLetterSpacing(self, QFont.SpacingType, float): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QFont'
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a solucionar el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución se encuentra en crear una instancia de `QFont` donde realizaremos los cambios necesarios para aplicarse despues en el metodo `setFont` del `QLabel`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLabel
from PyQt5 import Qt

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        font = Qt.QFont() # ++ Creamos la instancia de QFont
        font.setLetterSpacing(Qt.QFont.AbsoluteSpacing,20) # ++ Agregamos la propiedad indicada para asignar es espacio entre letras

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("hola")
        self.label.setFont(font) # ++ Indicamos la instancia de QFont en el Label


app =  QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```